# Batch file to replace special characters in subfolder in windows

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s /o-n ^|sort /r') DO (
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   pushd "%%~dpG"
   SET Var=%%~nfG
   SET Var=!Var: =_!
   SET Var=!Var:[=_!
   SET Var=!Var:]=_!
   SET Var=!Var:(=_!
   SET Var=!Var:)=_!
   SET Var=!Var:,=_!
   SET Var=!Var:'=_!
   rename "%%~nfG" "!Var!"
   popd
   endlocal
)
```

Not working getting error in prompt like

_! was unexpected at this time.

Can anyone answer or correct this plz.`enter code here`

Comment: I'd double quote all the `Set Var` like this `Set "Var=!Var: =_!"`

Comment: Agreed, because you haven't used double quotes you haven't prevented the 'special' closing parenthesis 'character' from closing your `DO` block

Answer (score 0):

Also I'd compare if the name is changed before trying to rename:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\08\05\SO_45521689.cmd
@echo off

FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN (
  'dir /a-d /b /s /o-n ^|findstr "[,'()\[\]]"^|sort /r'
) DO (
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   pushd "%%~dpG"
   SET "Var=%%~nfG"
   SET "Var=!Var: =_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:[=_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:]=_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:(=_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:)=_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:,=_!"
   SET "Var=!Var:'=_!"
   if "%%~nfG" neq "!Var!" rename "%%~nfG" "!Var!"
   popd
   endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET Var=!Var:)=_!
rem          ↑      this closing parenthesis closes the `... DO ()` code block.
```

Use

```
SET "Var=!Var:)=_!"
```

or

```
SET Var=!Var:^)=_!
```

Moreover, [you cannot specify a drive or path for `rename` target](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html). Use    `SET "Var=%%~nxG"` instead of `SET Var=%%~nfG`.

Be aware of that your script *ingurgitates* all exclamation marks if a file name contains any.

The following script should do the job keeping delayed expansion disabled. Please note that operational `rename` command is merely `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem choose initial directory
pushd "D:\bat\Unusual Names"
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s /o-n') DO (
   SET "_FFN=%%~fG"                                    File Full Name
   SET "Var=%%~nxG"                                    File Name + Extension
   call :renaming
)
popd
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:renaming
   SET "Var=%Var: =_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[=_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:]=_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:(=_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:)=_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:,=_%"
   SET "Var=%Var:'=_%"
   ECHO rename "%_FFN%" "%Var%"
goto :eof
```